# Connecting HM-10 and relay to Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, relay, ble

I have an 8 channel relay, an Arduino Uno, and this HM-10 bluetooth module: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B06WGZB2N4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06WGZB2N4)

**The Goal**
Send a number (1-8) from my Android phone via bluetooth to turn a relay on.

**The Problem**
I can't seem to get the bluetooth to reply to anything I send. I'm trying to use "Arduino Bluetooth" from the app store to send commands, but it either errors or ignores me and doesn't do anything. I can't communicate with the bluetooth from the Arduino IDE either.

**The wiring**
I'm SUPER new to small electronics, I suspect I'm not giving the system enough power and might need to give my relay its own 5.5v supply, but here's what I've got:

```
HM-10    | Uno    
-------------------
RX       | Digital 3     
TX       | Digital 2
VCC      | 3.3V
GND      | GND
```

```
Uno      | Relay     
-------------------
Digital 4       | IN8   
Digital 5       | IN7
Digital 6       | IN6 
Digital 7       | IN5
Digital 8       | IN4
Digital 9       | IN3
Digital 10      | IN2
Digital 11      | IN1
GND             | GND
5V              | VCC
```

The code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const int relayPins[] = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11};
SoftwareSerial HM10(2, 3);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  HM10.begin(9600);
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(relayPins) / sizeof(relayPins[0]); i++) {
    pinMode(relayPins[i], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(relayPins[i], HIGH); // set relays to OFF
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (HM10.available() > 0) {
    int relayNum = HM10.read() - '0'; // convert ASCII to integer
    if (relayNum >= 1 && relayNum <= 11){
        digitalWrite(relayPins[relayNum - 1], LOW);
        Serial.print("Turned on relay ");
        Serial.println(relayNum);
        delay(1000); // wait for 1 second
        digitalWrite(relayPins[relayNum - 1], HIGH);
        Serial.print("Turned off relay ");
        Serial.println(relayNum);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add some debugging code